# How to get data of deleted row?

Tags: excel, vba

I am curious whether there is possibility to get data from currently deleted row in Excel VBA macro? I found out that Target in Worksheet_Change is the new active row that gets focus after the deleted row. Is there any way I could possibly access the row that was just deleted to get some info from it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the below:

```
Option Explicit
'Declare as global variable
Dim str As String

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'When deleted you get the value of the global variable
    MsgBox str
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    'Get the value of the cell when selected & before deleted
    str = Range("A1").Value
End Sub
```

You create a global variable which will store the value of the cell when SELECTED & BEFORE deleted anything. When you delete you will receive a message box with the variable which holds the value you store when you select the cell.